# JAVA : SVG converter to PNG get 'pattern' wrong

Tags: java, svg, png, batik

I want to convert svg file to png format with batik1.7, my code like :

```
public static void convertSvgToPng(InputStream in, FileOutputStream fos) {
    try {
        PNGTranscoder t = new PNGTranscoder();
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(in);
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(fos);
        t.transcode(input, output);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (TranscoderException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

But some image can't convert, and get this wrong :

```
org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1
  The URI "#Unnamed_Pattern"
  specified on the element <pattern> is invalidat     org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGPatternElementBridge.extractPatternContent(SVGPatternElementBridge.java:260)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGPatternElementBridge.createPaint(SVGPatternElementBridge.java:86)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertURIPaint(PaintServer.java:359)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertPaint(PaintServer.java:259)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertFillPaint(PaintServer.java:228)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.PaintServer.convertFillAndStroke(PaintServer.java:146)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGShapeElementBridge.createShapePainter(SVGShapeElementBridge.java:117)
at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGDecoratedShapeElementBridge.createFillStrokePainter(SVGDecoratedShapeElementBridge.java:58) ....
```

When I open svg with TXT, there are mang "pattern" tag. After I delete all the "pattern" with a program, convert success, but lose some detall. I think it is not a good way to solve this problem.It have any other way to slove this problem? Please help me.

The problem file ：

```
jsfiddle.net/asdzheng/BtFbX/1/
```

Comment: We need to see the file you're trying to convert.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have put some detail of my svg. It's my first time to ask question here, forgive me not good at edit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have make it work after @BigBadaboom suggestion to use batik-rasterizer.jar replace batik-transcoder.jar. My codes are following :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.DestinationType;
import org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverter;
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;
import org.apache.batik.util.XMLResourceDescriptor;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class DOMRasterizer {

public Document createDocument(InputStream in) {
    Document doc = null ;
    try {
        // Create a new svg document.
        String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
        SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
        doc = f.createSVGDocument(null, in);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DOMRasterizer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return doc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DOMRasterizer rasterizer = new DOMRasterizer();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("your svg path"));
    Document svgXmlDoc = rasterizer.createDocument(in);

    // Save this SVG into a file (required by SVG -> PNG transformation process)
    File svgFile = File.createTempFile("graphic-", ".svg");
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(svgXmlDoc);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(svgFile);
    try {
        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(fos));
    } finally {
        fos.close();
    }
    // Convert the SVG into PNG
    File outputFile =new File("output path");
    SVGConverter converter = new SVGConverter();
    converter.setDestinationType(DestinationType.PNG);
    converter.setSources(new String[]{svgFile.toString()});
    converter.setDst(outputFile);
    converter.execute();
}
}
```

And I have the following JARs :

- batik-all-1.7.jar
- commons-io-1.3.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- xml-apis-ext.jar

Answer (score 0):

From the error it sounds like the file has a reference to a pattern ("Unnamed_Pattern") that doesn't exist.

What you could try is to search the file for the reference ("Unnamed_Pattern").  When you find it, it will probably be something like this:

```
fill="url(#Unnamed_Pattern)"
```

Then either delete the attribute, or change it to `fill="none"`.  Note that there may be more than one reference to that non-existent pattern in the file.

But to be absolutely certain, we need to see the original file, as Robert says.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have put some detail above.

Comment: Normally you only click the green check mark when an answer solves your problem.  It doesn't sound like this is the case yet for you.

Comment: Ok, obviously your patter does exist.  And seems to be valid (I tried it in a test file).  So my suggested explanation is not correct.  Unfortunately without some sort of test file that shows the problem it will be very hard to diagnose.  Is it possible you can reduce your file to something you *can* post that still gives the error?

Comment: Sorry about that green check , I will notice next time.

Comment: I want to post the image, but the website can't upload the image of svg. The edit box crash everytime when I post all the detail svg. How to give the file to you or post in this question? Thank you again.

Comment: You could create a new item at jsfiddle.net.  Just paste your SVG into the HTML field.  Click Run to check it works then Save.  You can then post the resulting URL here.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion and your patience. I have post the svg site, if it not work, please let me know.

Comment: The sample file you posted looks fine.  And Batik reports no errors with it. So it doesn't really help resolve your problem.

Comment: Was the problem file edited in any way after being exported from Illustrator?  If not, then perhaps you have encountered a bug in Illustrator.

Comment: I have post my convert code. It's different whit yours? Otherwise, maybe the different batik version?

Comment: I am not really know about the file have edited by Illustrator. Could you tell me what the influence after file export from Illustrator? can't open or can't convert? expect your answer.

Comment: The sample file you put here was created in Illustrator.  I am assuming the broken file was also made in Illustrator.  Illustrator should not be creating bad files.  I was just checking that no-one in your team edited the file by hand after it was saved from Illustrator.  If someone did, then they may have made a mistake.  If no-one changed the file, then perhaps there is a bug in Illustrator.

Comment: Re convert code: I just used the Batik test view (Squiggle) to test the file.  I also examined the file contents by eye.  I did not try using your code.

Comment: I'm afraid that I haven'e make the question clear. The sample file is exactly the problem file and it can be always opened by broswer. It's just can't convert by batik.jar with my way. My question is that if have some other way to convert sample file to png/jpg.

Comment: In the Batik distribution, there is a command-line program for converting SVG to PNG (batik-rasterizer.jar). http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html  Perhaps that will work better than the library.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very very kind! I have make it work after your suggetion.  o(∩_∩)o